# How To Read Input Fields From A Fieldset In JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this Fieldset:

```
<fieldset id="myFieldset" >
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="Testing">
</fieldset>
```

I tried to read the input value of the fieldset like this in javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myFieldset");
    console.log("The fieldset elements: ", x);

    var data = x.getElementsByTagName("username");

    console.log("The googleData elements: ", data);
}
```

But I'm not able to get the input section of the field set.

Comment: I Think you wil read the value of the input field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
(function(){
  var f = document.getElementById("myFieldset");
  var input = f.getElementsByTagName("input");
  console.log(input[0].value)
  
  var n = document.getElementsByName("username")[0];
  console.log(n.value);
})()
```

```html
<fieldset id="myFieldset" >
<input type = "hidden" name = "username" value = "Testing">
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

The tag name is `input`

`username` is the name (which you can search on with `getElementsByName` (no `Tag` in the method).

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
var data = x.getElementsByName("username");
```